# Block size of BKZ algorithm and related security of CRYSTALS-Kyber

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, kyber

Security of lattice-based schemes in the [NIST Posto-Quantum Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-Quantum_Cryptography_Standardization) often relies on the complexity of dual attack. Complexity of this attack depends on the running time of lattice basis reduction algorithm like BKZ$-\beta$, where $\beta$ is block dimension of BKZ-like algorithm.

I am looking at candidate CRYSTALS-Kyber. The dual attack works in lattice of dimension 795 and the best corresponding $\beta$ was chosen 870. I thought that $\beta$ must be smaller than the lattice dimension. That is not right?